# Test static responses RPC:S-7:AEC-0

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

we are trying to add In-App billing in our app. We took the logic from TrivialDrive example project, make some changes, so now we use Test static responses (like android.test.purchased...). When we requested puchase item, the [RPC:S-7:AEC-0] error shows up.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in item id, which wasn't correct.